# How to constrain a triangulation within a border (polygon/shapefile)?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, xyz, triangulation

I have a bunch of XYZ data and I want to triangulate a surface with them.

Easy enough. "create TIN", select my shapefile with the XYZ data and let ArcMap do the rest. However, I need to constrain my triangulation into some borders, as certain connections make no sense. **How do I give my triangulation some borders? (i.e. a shapefile)**

Let's assume I have only elevation data for some valley bottoms, whereas I don't have elevation for the mountain slopes between it. If I just triangulate it, I get wrong/misleading results:

[image: wrong triangulation]

It just triangulates over two valleys that don't have any connection, and due to their different elevation, I would get some flow lines, where I in fact have a mountain range. If I'd constrain the trianulation to the outline of the valleys, I'd get the correct result:

[image: correct triangulation]

But I can't seem to find an option for it.

The documentation (Fundamentals of creating TIN surfaces) says *"Hard breaklines represent a discontinuity in the slope of the surface. Streams and road cuts could be included in a TIN as hard breaklines. Hard breaklines capture abrupt changes in a surface and improve the display and analysis of TINs."* , which sounds like what I need, but if I add my border shapefile into "create TIN" and select "Hard_Line" for "Type", I just get my border to show up in my TIN, labeled "Hard Edge", but other than that, I just get the same, wrong, TIN. All the other options with "Hard" or "Line", do the same, e.g. "Hard_Clip" just triangulates all over it anyways, and then cuts away outside the borders, but leaving the inside just as is.

How do I triangulate within a specified border, which seems like a very obvious thing, that I apparently can't find.